# Вставка большого количества строк в TextArea JavaFX

Tags: javafx, textarea

Имеется `ArrayList<String>`, в котором хранится около 40 000 строк. Их необходимо вывести в `TextArea`. Пробовал реализовать через `Observer` и просто вставку через цикл. В обоих случаях получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException...
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Если сократить количество строк до ~100, тогда ошибки возникают только периодически. С помощью каких компонентов лучше реализовывать подобный функционал?

Пример добавления:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++) {
                    messagesArea.appendText(i + "\n");
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Стек:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.addTextRun(PrismTextLayout.java:755)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.addTextRun(GlyphLayout.java:140)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout.breakRuns(GlyphLayout.java:210)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.buildRuns(PrismTextLayout.java:770)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.layout(PrismTextLayout.java:1021)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.ensureLayout(PrismTextLayout.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.text.PrismTextLayout.getBounds(PrismTextLayout.java:246)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.getLogicalBounds(Text.java:358)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.impl_computeGeomBounds(Text.java:1168)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateGeomBounds(Node.java:3577)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getGeomBounds(Node.java:3530)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getLocalBounds(Node.java:3478)
    at javafx.scene.Node$MiscProperties$2.computeBounds(Node.java:6472)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9306)
    at javafx.scene.Node$LazyBoundsProperty.get(Node.java:9276)
    at javafx.scene.Node.getBoundsInLocal(Node.java:3156)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextAreaSkin$ContentView.layoutChildren(TextAreaSkin.java:207)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Весь код покажите. у TextArea есть метод setText().его и можно использовать.

Comment: Использую appendText()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо так (рекомендуемый вариант):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(textArea));
        primaryStage.show();

        MessageTask messageTask = new MessageTask();
        messageTask.messageProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> textArea.appendText(newValue));
        new Thread(messageTask).start();
    }

    class MessageTask extends Task<String> {
        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 40_000; i++) {
                updateMessage(i + "\n");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

либо оберните добавление текста:

```
final int j = i;
Platform.runLater(() -> textArea.appendText(j + "\n"));
```

Причина ошибки: работа с графическими компонентами JavaFx вне `JavaFX Application Thread`